# Macbook Air Logitech K120 USB Keyboard auto remapping problem

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, usb, keybindings, mapping

I'm having an issue with my 2013 MacBook Air. From day one, I've been using my Logitech K120 USB keyboard with it, and it worked flawlessly from first plug, no problem at all.

I've been a month away from home, carrying my MacBook only, no usb keyboard.

Now I'm back home and keyboard seems to be crazy. For instance, Home key and Page Up work now as Brightness- and Brightness+.

My layout is spanish QWERTY, by the way. Other keys malfunctioning, are ºª\ key (top left key) is working as >< key (left to Z key, next to bottom left).

I don't know what's causing this, and I don't see any setting where it may have been changed.

And Google isn't helping either, so you guys are pretty much my only hope.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your last words sound like Leia: "Obi One Kenobi you are my only hope"

Answer (score 1):

I think best solution it's made your own keyboard layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

I solved the problem that interchange "ºª" and "<>" key behaviour on Genius keyboard. 
https://github.com/equiman/ukelele-es-layout/blob/master/README.md

Maybe can help you too.